# Search an element in a hash table

Tags: perl, search, hashtable

I have created a hash table from a text file like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;

open my $fh, '<', 'tst' or die "failed open 'tst' $!";
while ( <$fh> ) {
  push @{$h{keys}}, (split /\t/)[0];
}
close $fh;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%h;
```

Now I want to look for a field in another text file in the hash table.
if it exists the current line is written in a result file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;

open my $fh, '<', 'tst' or die "failed open 'tst' $!";
while ( <$fh> ) {
  push @{$h{keys}}, (split /\t/)[0];
}
close $fh;


use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%h;

open (my $fh1,"<", "exp") or die "Can't open the file: ";

while (my $line =<$fh1>){

chomp ($line);



my ($var)=split(">", $line);

if exists $h{$var};
print ($line);

}
```

I got these errors:

```
syntax error at codeperl.pl line 26, near "if exists" 
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at codeperl.pl line 27. 
syntax error at codeperl.pl line 29, near "}" 
Execution of codeperl.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3):

What is there to say? The *statement* `if exists $h{$var};` is a syntax error. You may want:

```
print $line, "\n" if exists $h{$var};
```

or

```
if (exists $h{$var}) {
  print $line, "\n";
}
```

The other errors will go away once you fixed that. If you get multiple errors, always look at the *first* error (with respect to the line numbers). Later errors are often a result of a previous one. In this case, the syntax error messed up the parsing.

---

#### Edit

your main problem isn't the syntax error, it is how you populate your hash. The

```
push @{$h{keys}}, (split /\t/)[0];
```

pushes first field on the line onto the arrayref that is in the `keys` entry. To me, it seems that you *actually* want to use this field *as* the key:

```
my ($key) = split /\t/;
$h{$key} = undef;   # any value will do.
```

After that, your `Dumper \%h` will produce something like

```
$VAR1 = {
  '@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers' => undef,
  'a a pour les ressortissants des'              => undef,
  'a a priori aucune hiérarchie des'             => undef,
};
```

and your lookup via `exists` should work.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means (it doesn't help that I don't speak French). If you want to show example input (a good idea), please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17165808/edit) your question.

Comment: First, Sorry for my bad English :(    i have this in the hash table :$VAR1 = {
          'keys' => [
                      '@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers',
                      'a a pour les ressortissants des',
                      'a a priori aucune hiérarchie des',
                    ]
        };
in the input file "exp" there is this : "@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers > the buildings which (0.000000183067019)"  So the script will search for ""@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers" which is normally exist in the hash table.. but it cannot find it

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra Your hash only has one key: `keys`. See my update to see how to populate the hash correctly, so that it has multiple keys.

Comment: `use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;

open my $fh, '<', 'tst' or die "failed open 'tst' $!";
while ( <$fh> ) {
  my ($key) = split /\t/;
$h{$key} = 1;
}
close $fh;


use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%h;

open (my $fh1,"<", "exp") or die "Can't open the file: ";

while (my $line =<$fh1>){

chomp ($line);



my ($var)=split(">", $line);

if (exists $h{$var}) {
  print $line, "\n";
}
}   like this doesnt work also, it cannot find`

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra Ok, then what are the contents of the second file? For `exists` to return true, the key has to be equal character for character with the field from the file.

Comment: here is the content's the second file :   @ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers > the buildings which (0.000000183067019)
les btiments > parliament s buildings (0.000000178348259)
@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers > buildings in brussels (0.000000174492751)
les btiments > view to destabilizing (0.000000135872244)
les btiments > to destabilizing the (0.000000135872244)   So it must print the first line

Comment: Aha, so there is an extra space between the key and the `>`? Try to to split on the `/\s*>\s*/` regex (instead of `/>/`), let's see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

just try your code like this

First, build your hash

```
while(<$file1>){
    # get your key from current line
    $key = (split)[0];

    # set the key into the hash
    $hash{$key} = 1;
}
```

Second, judge

```
while(<$file2>){
     # get the field you want you judge
     $value = (split)[0];

     # to see if $value exists
     if( exists $hash{$value} ){
         print "got $value";
     }
}
```

Comment: what about `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: @M42 With `use strict` and `use warnings`, it can help you avoid some coding mistakes. The code above is just a hint.

Comment: @akawhy But are you aware that your code won't run under `strict`? Do you also know that `split` returns the number of fields in scalar context?

Comment: @amon Thank you for pointing out that. I'll make some changes of the code